# Office 2011 Mac, Sync calendars with google apps and iPhone

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, iphone, sync, google-calendar

Our office will be using Office 2011 for email contacts and calendar. Currently we are using apple mail/ical and address book. My primary concern is syncing calendars with google apps. That said our primary feature that we use google apps calendar for is sharing calendars.

Best way to using office 2011...

1. To sync calendars with an iPhone?
2. To sync/share calendars between users?
3. To sync contacts with an iphone?
4. To sync/share contacts with between users?

Users are on other computers and mostly work from home

Needs to be fool proof once setup :-)

I am not fond of the idea of syncing outlook with Mac address book and ical then to the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2011 Microsoft does not support CalDAV (necessary to support connection with Google Calendars directly) ...

And Google (Calendar Section) hasn't seen fit to write an APP that connects Outlook to Google Calendar using some other means ...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has explained that they have not included anything other than exchange sync in the first release of office 2011 (Outlook v14).

They have stated that they will bring Calendar support with SP1 which will be a free release in Q1/Q2 of 2011  (looks like Q2 now!)

For what it's worth Thunderbird with Lightening and Google Cal plugin works pretty seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

You can sync contacts and calendars with an iPhone through Google Sync (that works even with Google Apps). And you can share contacts and calendars between users right within Google Apps.

Are you asking if Google Sync is compatible with Outlook 2011?

If this is the case, AFAIK it isn't (it doesn't even support CalDAV).

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=2ae18f74721cba8e&hl=en
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook

Comment: I am simply asking for a solution to sync contacts and calendars between iphone-google-outlook. Right now contact syncing works. The fact that Microsoft does not have a solution does not mean there is no solution. Although Microsoft plans to support this discourages third party developers.

Comment: There is a partial solution here http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=044fe4493f88eba1&hl=en&start=40 , but I don't know if it can help you.